# Django : Limit records in database based on foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to limit the number of rows in `MyTable` to 2 per user

```
class MyTable(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submission = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Is it better to override the `save` method or check this in `form validation`? If it's save method, how do I return an error to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the clean method to check if there are already 2 rows in the table per user.

```
def clean(self):
    if MyTable.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()>=2:
        raise ValidationError('Only 2 entries per user allowed')
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. Any reason you prefer this over overriding save method?

Comment: Well, the clean method is there for this reason. This will propagate the validation error to the model form as well, and the admin, but if you override the save method, it's a bit problematic to show to the user why and when the error occurred.

Comment: The form doesn't have a `user` field, that's deduced from the currently logged in user i.e. `request.user`. It just gets the `submission` field from the `POST`

Comment: @dekomote This will fail if you try to save more than one row at once.
If we current count is 1 and you try to save 2 rows, clean will be called before saving so it will pass for both row.